# Why left join takes so much time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have created two temporary tables:

```
create temporary table temp.PromoCust (
    CustId int(10)
);

create temporary table temp.Inv (
    CustId int(10),
    InvId int(10)
);
```

Insert some data:

```
insert into temp.PromoCust
select pl.CustomerId
from promoline pl
where pl.PromoId = 3008;

select * from temp.PromoCust; -- count is 234.995 customers

insert into temp.Inv
select i.CustomerId, i.InvoiceId
from invoice i
where i.InvoiceDate between '2016-12-21' and '2017-01-03';

select * from temp.Inv; -- count is 86.684 customers and invoices
```

And finally I run a left join query:

```
select pc.CustId, i.InvId
from temp.PromoCust pc left join temp.Inv i
    on pc.CustId = i.CustId;
```

For some reason this takes forever. Is it something wrong with the query? I cannot really get any results from this.

Comment: MySQL has to handle a 234,995×86,684 Cartesian product and doesn't have indexes to do it.

Comment: If your original `PromoCust` and `invoice` table have proper indices, it will probably be faster to do `select c.CustomerId, i.InvoceId from PromoCust c left join invoce i on i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId and i.InvoceDate between '2016-12-21' and '2017-01-03' where c.PromoId = 3008` directly, instead of doing that bunch of temp table stuff

Comment: @AdrianShum I think that the where clause `where c.PromoId = 3008` does not yield the correct results. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @DimitrisP. Well, you should tell me why you think it does not yield correct result  :)  btw, I actually find one problem: I misread your original table as `PromoCust`. It should be `promoline` instead, so the sql should (just replacing the table name): `select p.CustomerId, i.InvoceId from promoline p left join invoce i on i.CustomerId = p.CustomerId and i.InvoceDate between '2016-12-21' and '2017-01-03' where p.PromoId = 3008` .  Essentially the same as original one

Comment: @AdrianShum Thank you Adrian. It was my mistake. I used a limit to experiment and it seems to work.